# How to reshape a 4d numpy array for training a model

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, lstm

I am trying to train my already compiled CNN and LSTM model. However I keep getting the error

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected
>   time_distributed_151_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with
>   shape (4732, 32, 32, 3)

My model summary looks a bit like this

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

time_distributed_151 (TimeDi (None, 3, 32, 13, 13)     4736

---

time_distributed_152 (TimeDi (None, 3, 32, 11, 11)     9248

---

time_distributed_153 (TimeDi (None, 3, 32, 5, 5)       0

---

I can't seem to expand my input shape to the 5 dimensional array it is expecting. After looking at various sources online, I have had no luck in being able to reshape my numpy array.

Any help would be brilliant

Comment: @AK47 Sorry here is a better look at the model summary.

Comment: Please post any and all text and code as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: @NilsWerner done

Answer (score 0):

You can use this piece of code:

```
x = np.array([[4732, 32, 32, 3]])
x.reshape(x.shape[0],-1)
```

I hope it works.